# To change the metatags of PNG Image files

Tags: asp.net, png, xmp, metatag

I am using PngCs dll to fetch the chunk data for Png image file in asp.net, I am able to do that but now I want to update the chunk data for that PNG.

I used PngWriter but it is creating whole new file without inheriting chunk data.

```
       PngReader pngr = FileHelper.CreatePngReader(path);
       pngr.GetMetadata().GetTxtForKey(PngChunkITXT.KEY_Title);
       Response.Write(pngr.GetMetadata().GetTxtForKey(PngChunkITXT.KEY_Title));
```

Below code is for writing new Png Image through PngWriter ,I want embed new itxt chunk while creating new file.

```
        PngReader pngr = FileHelper.CreatePngReader(origFilename); // or you can use the constructor
        PngWriter pngw = FileHelper.CreatePngWriter(destFilename, pngr.ImgInfo, true); // idem
        Console.WriteLine(pngr.ToString()); // just information
        int chunkBehav = ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL_SAFE; // tell to copy all 'safe' chunks
        pngw.CopyChunksFirst(pngr, chunkBehav);          // copy some metadata from reader 

        for (int row = 0; row < pngr.ImgInfo.Rows; row++)
        {
            ImageLine l1 = pngr.ReadRowInt(row); // format: RGBRGB... or RGBARGBA...

            pngw.WriteRow(l1, row);
        }
        pngw.CopyChunksLast(pngr, chunkBehav); // metadata after the image pixels? can happen
        pngw.End(); // dont forget this
        pngr.End();
```

for further reference click [this link](http://pngcs.googlecode.com/git/docs/html/classes.html)

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I tried to do my best ,please don't down vote for without any reason.

Comment: "without inheriting chunk data." What does that mean? What do you want to accomplish, and what do you get instead? YOu want to rewrite the same image with a new textual chunk? Bear in mind that a PNG can contain many textual (and other) metadata, you must decide what you want to do with all that.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,PngWrtiter is creating a file as same as the previous one ,but itxt chunk of png which stores metadata for file is not there ,that means image is looking just like the previous one ,but with out previous metadata.

Comment: I want to edit itxt chunk ,only itxt chunk stores the xmp metadata for png images

Comment: It's still unclear. Why don't you post the full code? It should be about 10 lines.

Comment: BTW: how do you know if the iTxt chunks is present or not? Are you aware that iTxt is just a generic text chunk, and that a PNG can contain many of them? You might want to use it for storing xmp metadata, but that's not standard.

Comment: I know png have many chunks ,but only iTXt contains UTF-8 text, iTXt chunk with the keyword 'XML:com.adobe.xmp' can contain Extensible Metadata Platform (XMP), according to wiki

Comment: Please correct me if I was wrong somewhere,I don't know much about that.

Comment: Now you have copied not your own code but code straight from the library. Sigh. You complain about downvotes, but you are less than helpful.

Comment: I was taking idea from it How can I create new file from PngWriter ,What I want ,I will create a new file with new iTxt metadata ,I have even tried method SetText but its not working working properly ,as it corrupts the whole image.

Comment: This problem has been solved by myself by using CsXmpToolKit.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been solved by using CsXMpToolKit.dll ,which is the best option to fetch the metadat from any type of file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
       PngReader pngr = FileHelper.CreatePngReader(origFilename); 
       PngWriter pngw = FileHelper.CreatePngWriter(destFilename, pngr.ImgInfo, true);                                                     
       pngw.CopyChunksFirst(pngr, ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL);
       pngw.GetMetadata().SetText(myKey, myText,false,false); // provide your own data  
       for (int row = 0; row < pngr.ImgInfo.Rows; row++)      {
            ImageLine l1 = pngr.ReadRowInt(row); 
            pngw.WriteRow(l1, row);
       }
       pngw.CopyChunksLast(pngr, ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL);
       pngw.End(); // dont forget this
       pngr.End();
```

Comment: Thanks but it was not like that ,I have not tried ,I tried lots of code by using this library ,but being new to this field I was not able to do that. Please do support to new developers ,when you do down votes ,stackoverflow block us ,and I think they  did to me ,now I cant post anymore ,that is the saddest part.

Comment: You "tried lots of code" but when we ask to show it, you don't. It's not the problem of being new developer. Did the above work? You can try  http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/ to check that the chunks are ok.

Comment: No its not working ,I think I have mentioned in my above comments that I have tried to use SetText ,but it dint work for me

Comment: "No its not working" What's the problem with you? I tell you for last time: EXPLAIN what's happening, what you did, what you get and what you expected. It's impossible to help you otherwise (not to mention, extrememely frustrating)

Comment: Getting error in  'ImageLine l1 = pngr.ReadRowInt(row);' ,saying 'Header checksum illegal'

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the code above? Are you sure of original PNG is not corrupt? (can you open it with tweakpng ?)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me this time ,that PNG was corrupt actually ,I am creating a UI to handle the XMP metadata for various image/file formats ,I had done with jpeg ,tiff ,pdf and now with png too. Sorry if I annoyed you ,but truly I tried your library a lot, actually I want to edit the itxt chunk i.e. without PngWriter ,thats why I was confused.